# Cumulative sum every time there is a change in at least one over 2 columns

Tags: r

Consider this simple dataset called `data` I'm working on:

```
  text          font_name           font_size
  <chr>         <chr>                   <dbl>
1 POND_RETRAITE BAAAAA+Arial-BoldMT        12
2 Pondération   BAAAAA+Arial-BoldMT        10
3 transversale  BAAAAA+Arial-BoldMT        10
4 finale        BAAAAA+Arial-BoldMT        10
5 du            BAAAAA+Arial-BoldMT        10
6 ménage        BAAAAA+Arial-BoldMT        10
```

I'd like to create a vector called `group_var` of length `nrow(data)` classifying each observation of `data`in a group. The group number should change every time there is a modification in either `font_name`, `font_size`, or both.

The first observation should have its own group. In this example, `group_var` should simply be :

```
[1] 1 2 2 2 2 2
```

The code I tried is:

```
group_var <- cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(data$font_size != lag(data$font_size, 
             default = data$font_size[1])) != 0 | diff(data$font_name 
             != lag(data$font_name, default = data$font_name[1])) != 0))
```

However this returns an incorrect output, as what should be the first element of a new group has its own separate group. See :

```
print(group_var)
[1] 1 2 3 3 3 3
```

Could you please help me figuring out this simple problem?

Comment: You could accomplish the same by converting to factors in base R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the function `consecutive_id` from `dplyr`

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
   mutate(group_var = consecutive_id(font_name, font_size))

           text           font_name font_size group_var
1 POND_RETRAITE BAAAAA+Arial-BoldMT        12         1
2   Pondération BAAAAA+Arial-BoldMT        10         2
3  transversale BAAAAA+Arial-BoldMT        10         2
4        finale BAAAAA+Arial-BoldMT        10         2
5            du BAAAAA+Arial-BoldMT        10         2
6        ménage BAAAAA+Arial-BoldMT        10         2
```

---

Note that you could accomplish the same using `data.table::rleid`

```
data.table::rleidv(df[-1])
[1] 1 2 2 2 2 2

with(df, data.table::rleid(font_name, font_size))
[1] 1 2 2 2 2 2
```

ant thus could be used as:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, group_var := rleid(font_name, font_size)][]
            text           font_name font_size group_var
1: POND_RETRAITE BAAAAA+Arial-BoldMT        12         1
2:   Pondération BAAAAA+Arial-BoldMT        10         2
3:  transversale BAAAAA+Arial-BoldMT        10         2
4:        finale BAAAAA+Arial-BoldMT        10         2
5:            du BAAAAA+Arial-BoldMT        10         2
6:        ménage BAAAAA+Arial-BoldMT        10         2
```